# What is causing a parse error in this program?

Tags: haskell

What is the problem here?

```
module Main
    where

import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    numbers <- ask -- parse error on input `numbers'
    putStrLn "The sum of all numbers is:"
    putStrLn $ sum numbers
    putStrLn "The product of all numbers is:"
    putStrLn $ product numbers

ask :: (Read a, Eq a, Num a) => IO [a]
ask = do
    putStrLn "Enter a number to add it to the list. Enter zero to terminate the list."
    input <- getLine
    let n = read input
    if n == 0
    then return []
    else do
        rest <- ask 
        return (n : rest)
```

Comment: Have you got any TAB characters?

Comment: @A.B. Do you have tabs and spaces mixed? This will confuse/break ghc

Comment: TABs are every 8 characters in Haskell.  Perhaps you have a mix of TAB and SPC.  It's best to avoid TAB entirely.

Comment: @jozefg most likely. I redid it with 8 spaces per indentation and now it works. At least the parsing, not the program.

Comment: I bet the problem is with the if statement. The indentation rules for if's in do blocks are quite crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the type signature of `putStrLn`:

```
> :t putStrLn
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Because `a` in `ask` doesn't have an explicit type signature, Haskell/GHC infers it from the methods you use it on.

So because you have a method `putStrLn a`, the only way this is possible is if `a :: String`.

**However**, in the type signature of `sum`:

```
> :t sum
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
```

`a` must be an instance of the `Num` typeclass.  (Your `ask` function also specifies this, as well).

GHC knows that `a` **must** be a `String`...but `sum` requires a `Num`.  `String` is not, at least in prelude, an instance of `Num`.

This is where the contradiction appears.

I recommend you use a program like `ghc-mod` to check your programs, you might get more helpful error messages.  Here is what I got:

```
No instance for (Num String)
```

Which aligns well with what we concluded.

The solution in this case would be to first turn your `Num` into a `String`:

```
> :t show
show :: (Show a) => a -> String
```

for:

```
putStrLn $ show $ sum numbers
```

Luckily, `printStrLn . show` is aliased as `print`:

```
> :t print
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

so you can use

```
print $ sum numbers
```

Comment: Why would this cause a parse error rather than a type error?